# What are possible scenarios why one should create a git commit in the past?

Tags: git, git-commit

Are there some use cases when creating commits with a past date is beneficial?

This is [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13340044/454103) and this is how it looks like in [GitHub](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/dummy/commit/a28a2db2080721f4ff0cec463a0465709aa1c825)

What is the effect of creating past commits on merging? Or is this just a log rendering issue? What I want to understand is, if people I work with start making past edits, what effects this can have on logs, merging, other extenal reports, etc.

Comment: I'm struggling to find one...

Comment: Importing from another VCS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use cases?

### GitHub Contributions calendar

I created an NodeJS application that creates dummy commits in the past to get a really nice GitHub contribution calendar: https://github.com/IonicaBizau/github-contributions

> #### [Contributions calendar](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-contributions#contributions-calendar)
>
> The contributions calendar shows how frequently you've been contributing over the past year. Clicking on a day shows the contributions made during that timeframe. If you hold shift and click on another day, you'll see your contributions in that timespan.

#### Exampe

After designing your GitHub contribution calendar (in browser) you click the <kbd>Generate</kbd> button:

> > [image]

The following JSON is generated:

```json
{
    "coordinates": [
        {
            "x": 6,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 6,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 8,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 8,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 11,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 11,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 12,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 12,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 12,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 12,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 13,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 13,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 13,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 13,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 13,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 14,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 14,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 14,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 14,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 14,
            "y": 7
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 15,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 16,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 17,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 17,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 19,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 19,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 19,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 20,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 20,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 21,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 21,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 21,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 22,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 22,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 22,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 23,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 23,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 25,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 25,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 26,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 26,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 26,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 26,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 26,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 27,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 27,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 29,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 29,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 30,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 30,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 31,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 31,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 31,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 31,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 31,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 32,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 32,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 33,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 33,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 35,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 36,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 37,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 38,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 38,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 38,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 38,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 38,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 40,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 40,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 40,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 40,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 41,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 42,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 43,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 43,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 43,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 43,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 45,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 45,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 46,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 46,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 46,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 46,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 46,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 47,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 47,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 47,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 48,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 48,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 48,
            "y": 6
        },
        {
            "x": 49,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 49,
            "y": 5
        },
        {
            "x": 51,
            "y": 2
        },
        {
            "x": 51,
            "y": 3
        },
        {
            "x": 51,
            "y": 4
        },
        {
            "x": 51,
            "y": 6
        }
    ],
    "commitsPerDay": 40
}
```

Then you just click the <kbd>Generate repository from data</kbd> button:

> [image]
>   If you can't see an gif image above, click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn3Fn.gif).

After downloading the generated zip file, just unzip it and push the repository on your GitHub account.

Then your GitHub contributions calendar can look like [**mine**](https://github.com/IonicaBizau):

> [image]

If you have any questions [just open an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/github-contributions/issues). :-)

Answer (score 3):

The only use-case that makes sense is an import from another versioning system. Say if you port from SVN other to Git, which is of course a very common use case. The only sane way do this is to transfer from an old system to a new system, i.e. to apply this transfer (hack) only once, and use good tools for the transition. Otherwise your data is basically corrupt. Once you have a corrupted system, there is no good way of doing things.

Comment: I would not say the only one... Say that you have some work to do during a month, but you do it all the last day. You may want to sparse your commit throughout the month to hide your procrastination.

Answer (score 2):

GitHub keeps track of your commits over time, and displays it publicly as your 'streak'.  One may want to create a commit in the past so one doesn't break the streak (though this is kind of cheating).

I've also seen commits in the past used to say "Of course I fixed that bug last week" (nice try, bub).